# How to get the following conclusion by a generator?

Tags: modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over field k. Let $M$ be an left $A$-module. $\Lambda:=\operatorname{End} _A(M)$. We know that if there is an exact sequence of the form 
$$0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N') \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N'') \rightarrow 0$$ 
of $\Lambda$-modules(here $N,N',N''$ are left $A$-modules), then we can not get an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow N' \rightarrow N \rightarrow N'' \rightarrow 0$ of $A$-modules in general.

But I have seen that if $M$ is a generator, then we can get an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow N' \rightarrow N \rightarrow N'' \rightarrow 0$.

The following is my consideration:
If $M$ is a generator, then $M$ contains $A$ as a direct summand. Suppose $M =A \oplus M'$ as $A$-module, then we write the exact sequence$$0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(A\oplus M',N') \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(A\oplus M',N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(A \oplus M', N'') \rightarrow 0.$$ Now I want to know  whether we can decompose the above exact sequence into two exact sequence: $$0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(A,N') \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(A,N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(A,N'') \rightarrow 0$$ and $$0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(M',N') \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(M',N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_A(M',N'') \rightarrow 0?$$ If we can, then I can get the conclusion. If we can't, is there other approaches to get the conclusion? Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the definition of *generator* that you are using?

Comment: @Stephen A  generator is a module that contains all indecomposable projecitve modules as direct summands.

Comment: So, it's a module $M$ such that every other module is a quotient of a direct sum of a finite number of copies of $M$. In that case, I suppose $A$ itself is a quotient of a direct sum of some number of copies of $M$ and hence a summand, but not necessarily a summand of $M$ itself (this happens already for matrix algebras and the vector representation as generator).